# Converting NSNumber to NSString issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, type-conversion

I know this is an issue that is already been asked a thousand times but of the few posted examples I've tried, I'm stilling running into issues.

Right now I'm trying to display a value to my debug log of an object that holds the data I need as an NSNumber. What I was trying was the following line of code:

```
NSString *distanceString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (NSNumber)self.selectedBeacon.distance ];
```

However, with the above I get the following error:

> Used type 'NSNumber' where arithmetic or pointer type is required

So then I tried the following:

```
NSString *distanceString = [NSNumber self.selectedBeacon.distance];
```

But when I went to type `self.selectedBeacon.distance` the line didn't appear in my intelisense. So for my third attempt I've tried the following line;

```
NSString *distanceString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [NSNumber self.selectedBeacon.distance]];
```

But the error I get is this;

> Expected ']'

Though I can see i have two closing brackets so that error has thrown me. Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: This is a very basic question and your attempts to solve the issue show that you can benefit greatly from working through a good book teaching Objective-C and C. ;)

Comment: Very true, I come from a more C#, C++ background and don't touch Objective C / iOS dev that much :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming `self.selectedBeacon.distance` is an `NSNumber`, then you can use `[NSNumber stringValue]` to get a string representation:

```
NSString *distanceString = [self.selectedBeacon.distance stringValue];
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try this..

```
NSString *distanceString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[self.selectedBeacon.distance integerValue]];
```

Comment: Nice and wise solution. thanx

Answer (score 1):

NSNumber is an object. You cannot refer to an object directly..

To get NSNumber value in string format, get its string value like this:

```
NSString *numberAsString = [myNSNumber stringValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just wont to log it via NSLog you can do

```
NSLog(@"%@",self.selectedBeacon.distance);
```

This will call `description`of `self.selectedBeacon.distance`
This works only for objects, though.